# Accessing nested properties using AppleScript

Tags: list, outlook, applescript

I have an applescript that I'm using to extract several pieces of information from an Outlook calendar event, including start date, title and attendees. The issue I'm having is with the Attendees class. I'm just trying to get the "name" property of the class, but I'm getting the following error. From what I can see, the "name" property exists as part of the "email address" property of the "attendees" class, so it's nested pretty deep. I'd like to create a list of just the attendee names.

Here's the error

```
Can’t get item 1 of {name:"Attendee Name", address:"attendee@address.com", type:unresolved address}.
```

Here's the script. You have to have a calendar event selected in Outlook first

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

global calendarTitle
global calendarDate
global calendarStart
global calendarAttendees
set show_note_in_new_window to true
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    delay 0.2
    set calendarEvent to selection
    -- if there are no tasks selected, warn the user and then quit
    if calendarEvent is {} then
        display dialog "Please select a calendar event first and then run this script." with icon 1
        return
    end if
    set calendarTitle to subject of calendarEvent
    set calDate to {month, day, year} of (current date)
    set calendarDate to calDate as text
    set calStart to start time of calendarEvent
    set calendarStart to calStart as text
    set calendarAttendees to get attendees of calendarEvent
    repeat with attendeeEmail in calendarAttendees
        set attendeeEmails to get email address of attendeeEmail
    end repeat
    repeat with attendeeName in attendeeEmails
        set attendeeEmailName to get name of attendeeName
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with attendee in attendeeEmailName
            display dialog attendee
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: can you say which line the error occurs on? Just from the error, it looks like you're treating a `record` like a `list`, which is throwing an error. But I don't have Outlook, so I can't see its scripting dictionary. I suspect one of the `repeat` loops is trying to iterate over a record, but I don't know which one.

Comment: the error occurs with the line `set attendeeEmailName to get name of attendeeName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
set emailList to get every email address of every attendee of calendarEvent

set nameList to {}
repeat with theName in emailList
    copy name of theName to end of nameList
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, above, I think what you want to do it something like this:

```
set calendarAttendees to get attendees of calendarEvent
set attendeeEmails to get email address of every calendarAttendees
set attendeeEmailNames to {}
repeat with thisEmail in attendeeEmails
    copy name of thisEmail to end of attendeeEmailNames
end repeat
```

line 2 collects the email addresses of every attendee into the list `attendeeEmails`, then line 3 through 6 extracts the names from each record and stores it  in `attendeeEmailNames`.  You might be able to do it all in one line (at line 2) like so:

```
set attendeeEmailNames to name of every email address of calendarAttendees
```

But I don't have Outlook to test this on, so I can't say for sure that would work.

Comment: I think this is getting closer. There was an error with the line `set attendeeEmails to get email address of every calendarAttendees` so I changed it to `set attendeeEmails to get email address of every item of calendarAttendees`.

Comment: There is a new error that occurs at line `set attendeeEmails to get email address of every item of calendarAttendees`. the error says `Can’t get email address of {required attendee 1 of calendar event id 10278 of application "Microsoft Outlook", required attendee 2 of calendar event id 10278 of application "Microsoft Outlook"}.` When I look a tthe dictionary, `email address` is definitely a property of the `attendee class` and the `required attendee class`, so I dont know why its not grabbing it